# Apply hashing to secure passwords generated within the app

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2012, windows-phone-8, sha

I have a created 150 odd predefined passwords and usernames in my windows phone 8 app.

They get initialized whenever the app starts.

Whenever a user enters the password and username, the app checks its authenticity and acts accordingly.

For obvious security reasons, i would like to protect my passwords so that the "extra-genius minds" don't find a way to manipulate them in their own app.

Could anyone tell how to use SHA-1 hashing and store those passwords into hashed formats.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
var sha = new SHA1Managed(); 
var bytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(password);
byte[] hashedPassword = sha.ComputeHash(bytes);
```